# Akka JVM: Test with multiple singletons failing because "name is not unique"

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I would like to test my framework based on a "master" singleton and multiple workers. The test I am trying to write would like to cover the standby recovery case. For that, I would need to be able to start several "masters" in the same JVM, but I get a "akka.actor.InvalidActorNameException: actor name [master] is not unique!".

Is there any way around that ?

Comment: How about using different names?

Comment: Well I use the name to find the singleton from the worker side, or maybe I am missing the point ?

Comment: Do you get the error while creating the master or while looking it up?

Comment: When creating the master

Comment: Then that's a design decision you need to make: Either your actor is supposed to exist only once and have a single unique name. In that case, you're testing a scenario which is not realistic. If your actor may exist more than once, you need to come up with a different naming strategy. Consequently, you'll have to adapt your lookup strategy (eg. use actorSelection with wildcards)

Comment: I guess I completely misunderstand something. This design is working fine when running on multiple nodes: I run several actors named "master" within the same cluster, and my workers can get the active one by using the Akka Singleton pattern. My issue is to try to reproduce this behavior on a single node for testing purposes.